# inno setup добавить драйвер в установку

Tags: inno-setup

Для создания установщика моей программы использую *Inno setup*.

С помощью [данной](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137424/how-to-make-vcredist-x86-reinstall-only-if-not-yet-installed/11172939#11172939) статьи удалось вшить _vcredist_x86.exe_ с проверкой, установлена ли она уже или нет. Также в программе будет использоваться устройство, к которому требуется устанавливать драйвер. Разумеется, этот драйвер хотелось бы вшить в установщик.

Как мне осуществить проверку, установлен ли этот драйвер в системе или нет (назовем файл с драйвером *driver.exe*)? Также как и со случаем _vcredist_x86.exe_ в приведенной статье.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят. Нашел product id интересующего драйвера в реестре по адресу:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

и вызвал функцию из [статьи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137424/how-to-make-vcredist-x86-reinstall-only-if-not-yet-installed/11172939#11172939), которая проверяла наличие программы, со своим значением product id.